# How can I reload my page on an iphone when the html5 video viewer is closed?

Tags: jquery, iphone

When I watch my html5 video on an iphone, it opens in the iphone video viewer. When I do not want to watch the video anymore (or the video is finished) I have to click the button "done" and the iphone video viewer closes. I wish that by clicking the button "done", my website reloads again. Is this possible with jquery?

```
<video id="myvideo"  
      poster="video.gif"
      data-setup="{}">
      <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
      <source src="video.webm" type='video/webm' />
      <source src="video.ogg" type='video/ogg' />
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
$(function () {
  $(window).blur(function () {
    location.href = location.href;
    location.reload();
  });
});
```

Whether the user closes the app, or navigates away, the `blur` event triggers, in that function, you can reload the page by resetting the `location.href` object.

Comment: @Jarla Are you using Cordova?